# A generic MVC ArrayAdapter class

Tags: java, android

Like everyone, I use `ListView`s in a lot of apps.  And I pretty much always end up making a custom Adapter.  Yet 90% of my custom adapters end up doing the same thing (mapping directly from an `ArrayList` or array) with `getView()` overridden to update the views.  I hate rewriting this part of the code.  I also hate that the code itself violates MVC so badly-  I want the view classes to directly read from the model, not have my control classes make dozens of UI calls.

This code is a solution to that.  Its a generic array adapter that can work on any model class, and calls a `setModel()` function on a view class that can be overridden to display different types of models.

It does have 2 weaknesses.  One is that I was forced to rely on reflection to avoid a weakness in Java generics-  you cannot call a generic constructor due to type erasure.  A factory interface could have been used instead, but since either is ugly I went with the way that requires less code in the clients.  The other is that it adds 1 extra `ViewGroup` per row of the `ListView`, where a custom implementation of this same pattern can avoid that, but I'm ok with that.

I guess I'm looking for opinions on the pattern and utility.  If you have ideas on how to get rid of the reflection that doesn't involve a factory class for each adapter instance I'm all ears.

This code has been tested for simple use cases, but not thoroughly.  More complex ones may fail, if so I apologize.

Edit:  I've changed the classes around a bit and made it so the id of the layout is not part of the adapter at all, and the view should know it.  This simplifies thing a bit.

This is the adapter class:

```
public class MVCArrayAdapter<ModelType> extends BaseAdapter{
    Activity ctx;
    ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
    Constructor<?> viewConstructor;

    public MVCArrayAdapter(Activity context, String viewClassName) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
        super();
        ctx = context;
        viewConstructor = Class.forName(viewClassName).getConstructor(Activity.class);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListViewRow<ModelType> view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>)convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            try {
                view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>)viewConstructor.newInstance(ctx);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        view.setModel((ModelType)getItem(position));
        return view;
    }

    public void add(ModelType object){
        array.add(object);
    }

    public void addAll(Collection<? extends ModelType> objects){
        array.addAll(objects);
    }

    public void addAll(ModelType... objects){
        for(ModelType object : objects){
            array.add(object);
        }
    }

    public void clear(){
        array.clear();
    }

    public void insert(ModelType object, int index){
        array.set(index, object);
    }

    public void remove(ModelType object){
        array.remove(object);
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<? super ModelType> comparator){
        Collections.sort(array, comparator);
    }
}
```

And the row view class:

```
public abstract class ListViewRow<ModelType> extends FrameLayout {
    ModelType model;
    View childView;

    public ListViewRow(Activity context, int viewLayout) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater( );
        childView = inflater.inflate( viewLayout,  this, false );
        addView(childView);
    }


    public abstract void setModel(ModelType newModel);

}
```

Here's an example child view class that sets a text field and a image field, to show the amount of work in creating the row view:

```
public class AdapterRow extends ListViewRow<String> {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;

    public AdapterRow(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.li);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
    }


    public void setModel(String str){
        tv.setText(str);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, few comments though:

- OOP is all about implementation hiding, so make sure you hide as much as possible.By default, instance variables are `package private`, which is the case for your variables.

  ```
  Activity ctx;
  ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
  Constructor<?> viewConstructor;
  ```

  I would rather hide them to the maximum by declaring them `private`.

  ```
  private Activity ctx;
  private ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
  private Constructor<?> viewConstructor;
  ```
- Information about `Activity` is available on construction time, and thus I would declare it `final`

  ```
  private final Activity ctx;
  ```

  -If you overriding a method, make you sure you annotate it by `@Override`

  ```
  @Override
  public int getCount(){
   //..
  }
  ```
- Do checks on your array boundaries,

  ```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   if(position < 0 || position >= size())
     throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();// or something more specific to your API
    return array.get(position);
  }
  ```

Comment: Agreed.  I forget the private frequently, its the C++ coder in me.  I forget that private isn't the default.  The getCount method is defined by the Adapter class (the grandparent class through BaseAdapter)-  I'm overriding that function and the name can't be changed.

Comment: @GabeSechan no problem, I didnt know that you it's overridden,and do annotate your methods by '@Override' when you override them